# Computing entropy from joint probability table

Tags: probability-distributions, information-theory, entropy

I'm teaching myself aspects of information theory. I found a book's chapter here: http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/cs286r/courses/fall10/papers/Chapter2.pdf. After reading this chapter a few times over, I still don't understand the following examples answers:

[image: Example]

In particular, what does `(1/8, 3/4)` in `H(1/8, 7/8)` mean? Why is `H(X|Y = 2) = 1`? Also, where does the `1/4` coefficient in `1/4 H(X|Y = 2)` come from?

EDIT:

```
P(Y = 1) = P(X = 1, Y = 1) + P(X = 2, Y = 1) = 0 + (3/4) = (3/4) = P(Y = 1)


P(Y = 2) = P(X = 1, Y = 2) + P(X = 2, Y = 2) = (1/8) + (1/8) = (1/4) = P(Y = 2)
```

Therefore,

```
H(X | Y = 1) = H( P(X = 1 | Y = 1), P(X = 2 | Y = 1)) = H(0, 1-(3/4)) = H(0, (1/4))


H(0, (1/4)) = (0 * log2 (0)) + ((1/4) * log2 (4))
```

but log2 (0) is undefined?? So, what I'm not understanding when computing  `H(X | Y = 1)`?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(X=2|Y=1)=1$, therefore $H(X|Y=1)=H(0,1)=0$. Note that, in entropy computations, terms of the form $0\log(0)$ are considered as equal to zero $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The notation $H(p,1-p)$ means entropy of a binary-valued random
  variable taking its two values with probability $p$ and $1-p$,
  respectively (the actual values are irrelevant).
- The notation $H(X|Y=2)$ means entropy of the random variable $X$ 
  conditioned on the event $Y=2$. Note that, conditioned on $Y=2$, $X$
  is a binary-valued random variable taking its two values with
  probabilities $\mathbb{P}(X=1|Y=2)=\mathbb{P}(X=1,Y=2)/\mathbb{P}(Y=2)$ and
  $\mathbb{P}(X=2|Y=2)=\mathbb{P}(X=2,Y=2)/\mathbb{P}(Y=2)$, respectively. It follows that corresponding entropy equals
  $H(\mathbb{P}(X=1|Y=2), \mathbb{P}(X=2|Y=2))$ (using the notation mentioned above). You
  can compute the required probabilities from the joint distribution
  given in the table and verify the result.
- By definition,

  $$ \begin{align} H(X|Y) &= \sum_y \mathbb{P}(Y=y) H(X|Y=y)\\
          & =\mathbb{P}(Y=1) H(X|Y=1) + \mathbb{P}(Y=2) H(X|Y=2) \end{align} $$

Comment: Referring to your first bullet point and slightly changing the notation, in this particular example, why is the chosen value of `X = 1/8` for `H(X)`? And what would be the chosen value to compute `H(Y)`?

Comment: Also, can you please elaborate more on my original question of why is `H(X|Y = 2) = 1`?

Comment: @John $\mathbb{P}(X=1)=\mathbb{P}(X=1, Y=1)+\mathbb{P}(X=1, Y=2)=0+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{8}$

Comment: I'm beginning to understand more after a lot of re-reading. Please see my update for a final clarification. Thanks